# How to configure a site to redirect automatically from HTTP to HTTPS in C#

Tags: c#, redirect, https

I set up SSL for my web site about one month ago.However,I have not never been used to that on the web site.
These are my problems:

- I entering manually as https the URL, so auto redirect not working.
- SSL have been working no problem at the https://www.mywebsite.com/a.htm ,but it's not working on those links e.g default.aspx , login.aspx.
- if I entered https as manually on some those pages,it redirecting automatically from https to http.

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    //  Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
    Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=windows-1254";

    if (Request.Url.Scheme == "https")
    {
        string URL = Request.Url.ToString();
        URL = URL.Replace("https://", "http://");
        Response.Redirect(URL);
    }
}
```

My question is:how to configure a site to redirect automatically from HTTP to HTTPS in C#?

Comment: Your code in Page_Load is currently configured to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP - if that's not what you want, remove it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `http` redirects to `https`:

```
if(!Request.IsSecureConnection) 
{ 
    string redirectUrl = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:"); 
    Response.Redirect(redirectUrl); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Application_BeginRequest` method of `Global.asax` page, check if the request is `http`. If so, replace the `http` with `https`:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection)
{
    string redirectUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally i prefer the Url-Rewrite Module for IIS:
https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

After installing the moudle you can add the redirect in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="https" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```